# Dynamic Navigation in a XAML Windows Store App

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I’m just looking for a sanity check before I go down this road with my Windows Store App.

In the app, I am looking to have a navigation model which involves the following:

All users shown the initial page, and are asked to make a section of Items from a list before tapping continue.

Each Item has a group of pages associated with it – could be 2,3, whatever.

The user is then presented the pages in the order that they are associated with for each Item and in the order by which they selected the Items.

For example, say the user selects Items 2 & 3.

Item 2 has PageA, PageB, PageC associated with it

Item 3 has PageB, PageD, PageA associated with it.

The user journey for the App would be

Selection -> PageA -> PageB -> PageC -> PageB -> PageD -> PageA -> End

The approach I am thinking of going with involves a “UserService” which is persistent throughout the app and stores a list of the Items the user has selected (in order)

I would then have a “PagePlayer” page which would act as a container for the pages to be displayed and this would be loaded after the user is finished with the Selection.
The player would then display all the pages in order based on the Items that were saved in the UserService.

I personally don’t want to go down this road because I know that having Frames displaying Pages etc is generally a bad idea, it could ruin the navigation history etc.

Which pages are associated with each item I would have saved to a local file of some sort and have this loaded when a new Item is set to be displayed.

The number of items are “hard coded” and have IDs associated with them.

I am familiar with Prism for WPF but unfortunately the recently released Prism for Windows Runtime does not support modularity for using a composite approach.

Apologies for general-ness of this question, I couldn’t think of another way of asking it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, one thing you could do is when the user selects their pages, you could create a Collection of these pages and then display them in something like a FlipView. Or, if you're using 8.1, use them to generate Hubs.

Comment: I love the Hub idea. Will investigate, thanks!